# print the output by clicking the + button (with js)

Tags: javascript

How to print any number of these inputs by clicking the + button?
(with the help of javascript)

```
     <div class="mb-3">
     <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">options</label>
     <ul id="my_list">
         <div class="input-group mb-3">
             <div class="input-group-text">
                 <input class="form-check-input mt-0" type="checkbox">
             </div>
             <input type="text" class="form-control">
         </div>
     </ul>

    <button type="button" class="mt-3" id="btn_p" onclick="child_new()" >+</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit How to Ask and take the tour to better understand how to use the site. In this case I believe your question is too broad for the specific Q&A format of the site. What you are looking for in an answer would have to be a relatively lengthy tutorial to accomplish all of these goals. Is there some specific aspect of this that is causing you trouble that you can focus the question to? If not, you may be better served just finding a tutorial, or getting started with an attempt and asking more specific questions as they arise. Good luck, and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

add this js:

```
document.getElementById("btn_p").addEventListener("click", function(){
window.alert(document.getElementById("TheInputThatYouWant").value)
})
```